# Problems writing TIFF files with ImageIO

Tags: java, image, image-processing, tiff, javax.imageio

I'm using Java 11, attempting to write compressed TIFF images with ImageIO. Most images write correctly, but some images throw an IIOException from within the javax.imageio code. My application is using Graphics 2D to resize images, then writing them to file. The Exception is:

> javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing TIFF file!

Here is the code snippet where I create the ImageWriter and write the image. The Exception is thrown from the last line in this snippet, tiffWriter.write().

```
//Create the TiffWriter, tell it where to write
ImageWriter tiffWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff").next();
tiffWriter.setOutput(imageOut);

//Wrap up the BufferedImage and Metadata in the IIOImage
IIOImage iioImg = new IIOImage(bi, null, meta);

//Set some writing parameters, so we get the G4 compression
ImageWriteParam writeParam = tiffWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
writeParam.setCompressionType(COMPRESSION_TYPE_GROUP4FAX);

//Write the image
tiffWriter.write(null, iioImg, writeParam);
```

The relevant stack trace entries are:

> File=TIFFImageWriter.java,Class=com.sun.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter,Method=write,Line=2612
>   File=TIFFImageWriter.java,Class=com.sun.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriter,Method=write,Line=2315

There is no further information given. So I'm not really sure what steps to take next. I know that I have write permission in the destination location. I can't seem to find any pattern with the images that fail the write operation. It seems like a roughly 20% failure rate in my sample.

Has anyone else experienced this error when writing TIFF files?

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I am setting the compression type to "CCITT T.6". The compression definitely has something to do with this error. If I omit the lines:

```
writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
writeParam.setCompressionType(COMPRESSION_TYPE_GROUP4FAX);
```

Then the IIOException is not thrown!
In my batch of test images, the same images fail no matter what the compression type is. But if there is no compression, all images are written successfully. 
So I guess the question is, why does writing a compressed image fail here?

Comment: I see (dead) javax :/

Comment: The CCITT T.6/Group 4 Fax compression is for bi-level (black and white) images only. Perhaps your images contain incompatible (ie. color or grayscale) data? It would be helpful if you can attach (or link) to one of the images that cause the exception. That said, I agree, the exception message could indeed be more helpful! :-)

Comment: From what I see on [`TIFFImageWriter.java` line 2612](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/91ab128a65a3/src/java.desktop/share/classes/com/sun/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriter.java#l2612), the exception you see wraps another exception. Can you also post the *full* stack trace with the root cause?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree with you that this is probably the result of a deeper  bit depth in the input image. I think my problem lies therein. 

Those were the only relevant stack trace entries. All other entries were within my program. You are correct that exception is thrown on line 2612, and the original exception is lost, no details are given. This is unfortunate, because I can think of many ways to report an incorrect bit depth error in a much more user friendly way. 

Now I just have to research how to transform to bit depth of 1, as Group 4 compression is required

Comment: @Eric I agree with you, *except* about the part "the original exception is lost". It's not. It may be that your code does not log it, or throws it away. But it *is* indeed included with the exception information thrown in `TIFFImageWriter` (as shown in the link above).

Comment: Thanks @haraldK, I'll have to improve my logging of these exceptions when they are thrown. I see now how TIFFImageWriter wraps the original exception.
By the way, bit depth was the problem, and I have found a solution. Java2S gives a nice demo of converting images to different bit depths : [Java2S ConvertUtil](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Providesusefulmethodsforconvertingimagesfromonecolourdepthtoanother.htm)
After implementing the methods in this class, the TIFFImageWriter writes with no problems

Comment: Keep in mind that self-answering is fully acceptable, and will earn you rep. 